# pyspark - merge two data frames with extra column in target

Tags: sql, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do merge like feature in SQL using pyspark. i have below 2 data frames as source and target.

```
source
    
id,name,city
1,abc,pune
2,xyz,noid
```

I want below target dataframe with 2 extra column

```
id,name,city,createdAt,lastupdatedAt
1,abc,pune,current_time,current_time
2,xyz,noida,current_time,current_time
```

Here key column is `id` field. So if there is any change in the source data frame my target data frame should reflect the same. if source is having updated data, target field `createdAt` remains the same and we updated the `lastupdatedAt` field. If source is having new data, target field `createdAt` should be updated while the `lastupdatedAt` field remains the same.

Can someone please help me with the logic or if need to make any design changes to achieve this requirement.

Thanks in advance,
Wasim

Answer (score 1):

please check delta lake implementation for implementing this
[1]: https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-python

Also can be achieved in spark itself using full outer join to check update in records on the basis of columns.

Comment: thanks for your input. i am trying with join condition but not able to add two extra column in target data frame and update is as needed. Could you please help me with any sample code or anything like that.

Comment: you need to use .withColumn('Createddate',current_timestamp()). As I am guessing this requires some kind of updating you need to use when and otherwise to update post doing join.

Comment: I want to add timestamps data only if  source data is new and last updated only when source data is updated.